# Self-designed class with ArrayList HELP!@!

Tags: java, class, debugging, arraylist, symbols

```
 //  This class reads in integers and puts the values into a set
  2 
  3 import java.util.ArrayList;
  4 import java.util.*;
  5 
  6 class Set {
  7 
  8     private ArrayList<Integer> members;
  9     private static int quantity = 0;
 10     
 11     // Constructors 
 12     public Set()    {
 13         new ArrayList<Integer>();
 14     }
 15     
 16     public Set(int member){
 17         new ArrayList<Integer>();
 18         addMember(member);
 19         quantity++;
 20     }
 21     //  Accessors
 22     public static int getQuantity() {
 23         return quantity;
 24     }   
 25     
 26     //  Mutators
 27     public void addMember(int member)   {
 28         members.add(member);
 29     }   
 30     // toString() method
 31     public String toString() {
 32         int i;
 33         System.out.print("[");
 34         for(i=0; i<getQuantity(); i++){
 35             System.out.print(this.get(i));
 36             if(i+1 == getQuantity())
 37                 System.out.println("]");
 38             else
 39                 System.out.print(", ");
 40         }       
 41     }   
 42     
 43     // Return true if 'this' is a subset of 'set', 
 44     // otherwise return false.
 45     public boolean isSubset(Set set) {
 46         if(this.contains(set))
 47             return true;
 48         else
 49             return false;
 50     }
 51     // Return true if 'this' is equals to 'obj',
 52     // Otherwise return false
 53     public boolean equals(Set set)  {
 54         return (this.contains(set) && set.contains(this));
 55     }
 56 }
```

So this is the first time I'm creating my own class with the ArrayList class. Previously I created my own classes with primitive data types but now since there is an ArrayList I'm confused with what constructors, accessors and mutators to put in (where I should put the 'this' reference etc.)

```
Set.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                        System.out.print(this.get(i));
                                             ^
  symbol: method get(int)
Set.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
                if(this.contains(set))
                       ^
  symbol: method contains(Set)
Set.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
                return (this.contains(set) && set.contains(this));
                            ^
  symbol: method contains(Set)
Set.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
                return (this.contains(set) && set.contains(this));
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method contains(Set)
  location: variable set of type Set
4 errors
```

These are the 4 errors which I keep getting. Other than that. Can anybody help me with the proper syntax for like, creating a class with ArrayList wrt the accessors mutators constructors etc.

The code here probably has a lot of flaws. Help would be much appreciated. It's like I'm doing this blindfolded :/

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the current instance of your class Set.  In that class instance, you have a member named `members`, which is the reference to the ArrayList.

When trying to call the methods of that class' instance, you must give it the correct variable name.

`members.get(i)`

`members.contains(set) && set.members.contains(this)`

Comment: What if I added this code?                                          public int getMember(int member)    {
 23         return this.get(member);
 24     }
Would it change whether I need to use 'this'? How would it change what you've said about members.get(i) etc.?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.
Here instead of `this` you should use your instantiated array list members.

Also in the `toString` you have not added return statement as it returns String as per your method definition.I have made changes to remove those errors you may now change as per your requirement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.*;

   class Set {

      private ArrayList<Integer> members;
       private static int quantity = 0;

      // Constructors 
      public Set()    {
          new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }

      public Set(int member){
          new ArrayList<Integer>();
          addMember(member);
          quantity++;
      }
      //  Accessors
      public static int getQuantity() {
          return quantity;
      }   

     //  Mutators
      public void addMember(int member)   {
          members.add(member);
      }   
      // toString() method
      public String toString() {
          StringBuilder string =  new StringBuilder();
          int i;
          System.out.print("[");
          string.append("[");
          for(i=0; i<getQuantity(); i++){
              System.out.print(members.get(i));
              string.append(members.get(i));
              if(i+1 == getQuantity())
                 System.out.println("]");
              else
                  System.out.print(", ");
          }  
         String returnString = string.toString();
          return returnString;
      }   


    // Return true if 'this' is a subset of 'set', 
      // otherwise return false.
      public boolean isSubset(Set set) {
          if(members.contains(set))
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
      // Return true if 'this' is equals to 'obj',
      // Otherwise return false
      public boolean equals(Set set)  {
          return (members.contains(set));
      }
  }
```

Comment: thanks. first time i've seen the stringbuilder function. so let me clarify. what you're saying is that if i have this arraylist in this class i should be making reference to 'members' rather than 'this'?

Comment: yes as you were calling methods of members using 'this' and check examples like http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword for using this keyword.Please let me know for any other help i can offer.

Comment: Dear user3274993 you can appreciate the answer by accepting it as an answer or by voting up the answer.